# getComputedStyle returning font-size: 0px in custom web component

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, custom-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to get the font size from the calling document in a vanilla javaScript custom component.

When I call:

```
var div = shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div));
```

I get a CSSStyleDeclaration with everything set as you'd expect:

```
font: "normal normal normal normal 24px/normal Times"
fontFamily: "Times"
fontKerning: "auto"
fontSize: "24px"
fontStretch: "normal"
fontStyle: "normal"
fontVariant: "normal"
fontVariantLigatures: "normal"
fontWeight: "normal"
```

But when I call any of the following on the next line:

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div).fontSize);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div)['font-size']);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div)['fontSize']);
```

It returns '0px'.

Even when I call the same methods using 'font', it returns 'normal normal normal normal 0px/normal'.

Any idea why or how the CSSStyleDeclaration is being reset and how I can get around it. Or is there an easier way to get the calling doc's font context in the shadowDom template?

Comment: What's `shadowRoot`? Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Make sure that you calling the script after all the DOM are loaded

Comment: @j08691 This is a custom web component which I don't think you can do in jsFiddle as it's configured now. (Can't link to an html file using `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/block-font/src/my-component.html">`

`shadowRoot` is the result of calling `document.createShadowRoot();` which is how you inject a web component template into the document.

Comment: @Pik_at - The script is definitely called after the DOM is loaded because I get the proper values in the call right _before_ I call for 'font-size'.

Comment: I created a fiddle to give an idea of what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't break because it's not in an html import: http://jsfiddle.net/focomoso/arpL9odb/3/